# some module has no attribute 'something' for tkinter to work with two python files

Tags: python

I trying to execute file 'B'. But I get some error as :
'module 'B' has no attribute 'view_note''

'''                                file >> A.py                         '''

```
 import B as b
 #from B import obj_2


 class obj_1:
     def __init__(self):
         print('obj_1 >> __init__')

     def obj_1_func_1(self):
         print('obj_1 >> obj_1_func_1')

   
         b.view_note.set("Infomation Updating...")
         # b.obj_2.display(self)
```

'''                                file >> B.py                         '''

```
 import A as a

 from tkinter import *
 import tkinter as tk

 class obj_2:
     def __init__(self):
         print('obj_2 >> __init__')

         self.view_note = StringVar()

         root.title("TK TEST")
         root.geometry("150x100+10+8")

         n1 = tk.Label(root, textvariable = self.view_note, fg='black')
         n1.pack()

         self.obj_2_func_2()

     def display(self):
         self.view_note.set("Infomation Updating...")

     def obj_2_func_2(self):
         print('obj_2 >> obj_2_func_2')

         a.obj_1.obj_1_func_1(self)




 if __name__ == '__main__':
     root = Tk()
     application = obj_2()
     root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where do you think you have defined `view_note`?  What is the full stack trace for the error?

Comment: I defined it in file B

Comment: No, you defined a `obj_2.view_note` there

Comment: You probably need to do something like b.object_2().view_note.set(...)

Comment: But file A is recognize it as 'b'. error: b.view_note.set("Infomation Updating...")
AttributeError: module 'B' has no attribute 'view_note'

Comment: Noticed how you are not using `view_note` in B.py but you have `self.view_note` instead? You have to find out (or create one) what is the equivalent of `self` in your A.py

Comment: sorry sir, I don't know how to use 'self' key word with python

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, module "B" has no attribute "view_note". What it has is a class `obj_2` objects of which have view_note attributes.
If you want to use this attribute in A first you have to instantiate the class with something like `obj_b = b.obj_2()` and then access it with `obj_b.view_note`.